# Is there a option to develop web API in sharepoint

Tags: asp.net-web-api, sharepoint

How can we have web API in sharepoint solution? I need to use this web APIs in web part of sharepoint solution.

Comment: is this On Premise or O365 ?

Comment: If this is SharePoint online, you can use SharePoint Framework to create your own webPart that uses your Web API for example

Comment: it is On Premise. I am aware of using Web API in webPart but looking for possibility to host web API in on Premise sharepoint